# Web config managing two URLs

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a .net web application that currently all users login through the same path.  myWebsite.com.

I am now wanting to implement a strategy for a specific set of customers who will have already logged in (think SSO) and provide them with their own unique URL, so I know that they are that customer and I can handle accordingly.

myWebsite.com/Colors/Red
this would load myWebsite.com/Colors/Red/RedHomepage.aspx

myWebsite.com/Colors/Blue
this would load myWebsite.com/Colors/Red/BlueHomepage.aspx

Can I do this within web.config?

Comment: check `RouteConfig`

Comment: @techspider this is not an MVC application.  This is a classic old school web application.